# How does HK-47 treat children?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

While watching a *Best of HK-47* I came to the question: "How does HK-47 treat children?".

In [this video](https://youtu.be/1CqpGfWrmc4?t=2m56s) from *Star Wars Knights of the Old Republic II: The Sith Lords*, [he says](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Wookieepedia:Quote_of_the_Day/Archive/HK-47):

> HK-47:
>
> > Answer: Oh, master, I could not allow myself to harm another. What if they have families? Or children? We must always think of the children. The littlest ones always suffer in war. Musing: I think perhaps I would enjoy learning a new language. Or watching an informative holovid.

Sure, it could be just sarcastic, but I can't remember a scene of him hurting a child.

So is there any reference, or did any other HK-Model this so?

Comment: That quote isn't sarcastic, but it is misleading. On Nar Shaddaa you can buy a "Pacifism package" for HK-47, and when you install it he says that (among other lines). The Exile is so unsettled that you remove it immediately, and he begs you to never do it again

Comment: Like small organic meatbags.

Comment: @WadCheber Question: Is there a quote?

Comment: @JasonBaker Thanks, i don't have the game for the reference any more.

Comment: @AlexH - Well, he calls all humanoids "organic meatbags".

Comment: Also, I don't remember any parts of KOTOR or KOTOR II in which HK-47 encountered a child.  Mission was the youngest person he met, and even if he wanted to treat her badly, Zaalbar was a strong incentive to not do so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To my knowledge, we've never seen HK-47 encounter a child in a scripted scene<sup>1</sup>. Nor does he describe any interactions with children during the sidequest to unlock his memories in *Knights of the Old Republic I*.

The closest we come is some dialogue in [*Star Wars: Galaxies*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Galaxies), an early (ish) MMO where HK-47 appears in several quests on Mustafar. If you return him to his body<sup>3</sup>, he "rewards" you with a "Kill one meatbag free" card (emphasis mine):

> I do want to thank you for all you have done for me up to this point. As a parting gift, you may tell me the name of some meatbag that you do not like and I will personally kill them. Oh why not, **I'll throw in the rest of their family for free.**

While this isn't evidence that he ever *did* kill a child, it does indicate that there's no particular moral compunction preventing him.

---

<sup>1</sup> Obviously, since he mostly appears as a party character in the *Knights of the Old Republic* video games, you could have him in your party in a situation where you are around and/or interact with a child. But [the dev team does **not** think of everything](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DevelopersForesight)<sup>2</sup>, so I'm not going to count that

<sup>2</sup> TVTropes Link. [All hope abandon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inferno_(Dante)), etc. etc.

<sup>3</sup> He's been hanging out in a ship's computer for the last few thousand years

Comment: Thank you very much. I guess this applies to other HK implementations, as well?

Comment: @AlexH With varying degrees of arbitrary sociopathy, I'd say yes; HK-47 probably wouldn't kill a child just because it was in front of him, for instance, but an HK-50 perhaps would